# Who killed the crew of the Venture in "The Lost World"?

Tags: jurassic-park, the-lost-world-jurassic-park

Towards the end of *The Lost World*,

> a ship carrying a T-rex has its crew slaughtered.

I think it is implied the T-rex did it. But the bridge looked intact and is too small for her to get into and eat people. My first thought was raptors, but these are not mentioned.

Is this explained anywhere?

I would ask what happens in the book, but it looks like that whole section was not in the novel.

Comment: I think the positioning of one of the corpses at the controls was to suggest that they had dragged themselves there to shut the hold on the Rex after it woke up and went nuts.  But I don't know how plausible that is or what the script says, so I'll let one of the script wizards say.

Comment: This missing detail made the film bizarre.

Comment: @Radhil: More precisely, there was a torn off hand at the controls. So you're saying that severed hand dragged itself there on its own?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - The Addams Family being on the ship is as likely as anything else I've heard

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's been a rumor for years that in a deleted scene, the crew was killed by raptors. IMDB's trivia page says the following:

> The script called for a scene where the Velociraptors got on board the Venture as it was about to set sail. As chaos ensued, the T-Rex also got loose, and killed everything else aboard. This explains why many of the crew members are dead in places the Rex cannot reach. The scene was never filmed.

IMDB can be pretty poorly-sourced. I've seen a bunch of "geek sites" repeating this claim, but to my knowledge no one has ever tracked down the actual source for this statement.

Meanwhile, the theatrical release shows the T-Rex as the only dinosaur aboard the Venture, and there isn't even a deleted scene hinting at raptors. So the unsatistifying canonical answer is that the Rex killed the sailors, even in tiny places it seemingly couldn't reach.

Answer (score 2):

None of the prevalent explanations make sense.

1. **Velociraptors** : If they got on the ship, when did they get off? Jumped out of ship in open ocean by themselves? If it happened on the island shore, who navigated the ship to San Diego?
2. **T-Rex** : If T-Rex killed everyone, who locked it up? Did it go in cargo by itself?

Here is my *attempt* for a better explanation:

After the ship left with the T-Rex locked up in cargo hold, it was set on some kind of auto-pilot (*it is fiction after all*) mode to reach San Diego. Suddenly, a group of [Pteranodons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pteranodon) attacks the ship. They kill everyone on board and fly away. This also explains crew getting killed in tiny places. They pulled them out with their long and strong beak.

Points which support this theory:

1. Pteranodons were indeed shown in the film. The film ends with a shot of a Pteranodon landing on a tree branch.
2. [Spielberg indeed wanted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park_III#Creatures_on_screen) to show Pteranodons but then he had to cut them out because of budget reasons.

Comment: This seems like pure guesswork.

Comment: Yes it is, but so are the others!! As we know there is no official explanation. But this one is more logical than the other guesses.

Comment: “Velociraptors : If they got on the ship, when did they get off?” T-Rex could have eaten them eh.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the deleted scene is correct. If you read both of the original novels, the films take portions of them and incorporate their versions across the trilogy. 
In the novel part of the pressure for Grant to make it back to the main building is they saw Raptors aboard the ship and needed to call to warn them. My guess would be this deleted scene was an interpretation of that that didn't make the cut.